# Концепция Fail-Fast итераторов

Tags: concurrency, теория, итераторы

Доброго времени суток.

Если я правильно понимаю, Fail-Fast итераторы сразу прекращают работу (обычно посредством генерации исключений), если обнаружат, что набор данных по которому они итерируются был изменен после того, как началась итерация (или с момента создания итератора).

**Вопрос:** почему в случае итераторов подход "могу читать до тех пор, пока никто ничего не изменил" предпочли подходу "могу вносить изменения только тогда, пока никто ничего не читает"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделано по одной простой причине: так дешевле. В противном случае пришлось бы отслеживать все живые итераторы - а это дорого. Особенно на старом C++ без rvalue-ссылок или на языках со сборкой мусора.

Comment: Но можно было бы добавить в итераторы метод close() и вести внутри коллекцию счетчик живых итераторов. Создали итератор - счетчик увеличелся на единицу, вызвали close() у итератора - счетчик уменьшился на единицу. Сделать проверку, чтобы нельзя было у одного и  того же итератора по сто раз вызывать метод close() задача тривиальная.

Comment: Ага, а если пользователь забыл вызвать close - коллекция теперь рид-онли? Это противоречит идее сборки мусора.

Comment: Касательно забывчивости пользователей - это совсем не те проблемы, которые надо решать, т.к. это борьба с ветряными мельницами. Концепция Fail-Fast итераторов применяется и в языках без сборки мусора. Однако мысль о связи концепции сборки мусора с решением отдать предпочтение писателям перед читателями - интересна. Вас не затруднит раскрыть её более подробно?

Comment: @Bakuard языки без сборки мусора (читаю как C++) при появлении концепции страдали от отсутствия перемещения, из-за чего любой подсчёт ссылок выливался в кучу "подергиваний" счётчика при любом чихе.

Comment: @Bakuard а в языках со сборкой мусора попытки (строгого) подсчёта ссылок выливаются в деградацию производительности. Просто подумайте как вы их будете считать без метода close.